# Accessing IPython functionality from the debugger

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

I have noticed that some of the `ipython` functionality is not available from  the debugger. For example, the `?` and `??` operands for variable introspection don't work:

e.g.

```
ipython> run my_script.py
ipython> %debug
ipdb> foo?
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax(<stdin>, line1)
```

Is there a way to bring the full `ipython` functionality to the debugger?

Answer (score 4):

`ipython` runs Python debugger `pdb` for debugging, so you are limited to commands offered by `pdb` (type `h` for a list) plus standard Python syntax (you may replace `foo?` with `help(foo)`).

If you want to start IPython shell at an arbitrary position in your code you can try [Embedding IPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython).

Comment: Thanks! but I guess that if I embed an IPython shell, I will not have access to the `ipdb` commands (i.e. `continue`, `next`, etc.). Am I correct? Is there a way to have the best of both worlds?

Comment: I think it is not possible in vanilla ipython, but I also found this package: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb (I haven't tested it)